# Trying to add a combobox within datagrid which has an itemsource already

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, datagrid

If I have a combo box by iteself with an item source e.g.:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Combobox.Options}"/>
```

This works fine. Where Combobox.Options is a list of strings {"option1","option 2",... etc}

However, I want to have a combobox within a datagrid which has an item source:

e.g.:

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="False"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Users.Table.Tables[0]}">
```

But I keep getting an empty combo box when I add it into a datagrid template column. I have also tried the Find Ancestor Relative soure but also got an empty combo box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to find the problem. Needed to add a DataContext when getting the list for the item source within the datagrid:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}"/>
```